# Python function returning many arguments

Tags: python, function

I know, it's a noob question..

I have these variables:

```
pgwdth = 30;  
mrgn = 0;  
fmt = True
```

And this function:

```
def Param(x,pgwdth,mrgn,fmt):
    parametros = x.split(" ")
    if parametros[0][1] == "p":
    numerozinho = int(parametros[1])
        print "Changing pgwdth"
        pgwdth += numerozinho
        print pgwdth
    elif parametros[0][1] == "m":
        numerozinho = int(parametros[1])
        print "Changing mrgn"
        mrgn += numerozinho
        print mrgn
    elif parametros[0][1] == "f":
        numerozinho = parametros[1]
        print "On/Off"
        if numerozinho == "on\n":
            fmt = True
        elif numerozinho == "off\n":
            fmt = False
        else:
            "Error"
        print fmt
    else:
    print "Error"
```

I just want it to return the variables that it used as arguments after changing it.

Comment: `return x,pgwdth,mrgn,fmt` as the last statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
return x,pgwdth,mrgn,fmt
```

Simple as that.

And where you call it:

```
val1,val2,val3,val = Param(x,pgwdth,mrgn,fmt)
```

Answer (score 3):

A function returns exactly *one* result. The trick is to make that result a *tuple* containing the multiple values.

```
return (x, pgwdth, mrgn, fmt)
```

In Python syntax the braces around the tuple are optional so you'll more often see

```
return x, pgwdth, mrgn, fmt
```

Which looks like returning multiple values, but now it's clear there is really just one return value

Comment: Little quirks like that make Python harder to read, but more interesting to code.